# Creating server side map overlays for android maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm currently working on an app that records travel patterns of all the app's users and allows them to see all of the routes people have traveled in the form of PolyLines.

Currently every time the user opens the app it sends a GET request to a PHP script that queries a database and returns the LatLng details of all the routes taken.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a v2 overlay server side, and instead of the app requesting all of the LatLngs the server could just send back an overlay to be applied to the map.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Any imagery you create server-side could be applied using the GroundOverlay or a TileOverlay(if the server can produce tiled images of the line). Please refer to the following links for more details:

1. GroundOverlay:
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay
   https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay.html
2. TileOverlay:
   https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay.html
   https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html